# How to draw interactive frame over user's desktop using java applet?

Tags: java, applet, screen-capture

I need to capture portion of user screen usign java applet. It is easy to do using Robot class but I'd like user to select which portion of screen to capture in draggy-droppy way.

So I need to draw rectangular frame over users desktop and response when user resizes it.

How could I do it? Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Root Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for an example that shows you how to use a Glass Pane.